# Best approach to use Laravel Blade with Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have 2 projects that are a Laravel + Vuejs ( Frontend - not using SPA ) and Laravel only for API. My problem is that my frontend page is like e-commerce like a website that I must have a good Search Engine Optimization.

So I decided to make this project with Laravel Blades and some components with Vuejs for fast manipulation. The problem is that my project is growing and my App.js becoming very large

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

import Vue from 'vue'
import Loading from 'vue-loading-overlay';
import 'vue-loading-overlay/dist/vue-loading.css';
import UserService from './service/user-service';
import CartService from './service/cart-service';
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate';
import StorageService from './service/storage-service';
import Toasted from 'vue-toasted';
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css';

Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);
Vue.use(Loading);
Vue.use(Vuelidate);
Vue.use(Toasted);

Vue.prototype.$userService = new UserService();
Vue.prototype.$cartService = new CartService();

const storageService = new StorageService();

const userModel = storageService.getUserStorage();
const cartModel = storageService.getCartDataStorage();
if(cartModel) {
    Vue.prototype.$cartService.cartModel = cartModel;
}
if(userModel) {
    Vue.prototype.$userService.userModel = userModel;
}

Vue.component('prodlist-component', require('./components/ProductListComponent.vue').default);

Vue.component('filterinput-component', require('./components/FilterInputComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('filtercategory-component', require('./components/FilterCategoryComponent.vue').default);

Vue.component('usermenu-component', require('./components/UserMenuComponent.vue').default);

Vue.component('auth-component', require('./components/modal/AuthComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('login-component', require('./components/modal/LoginComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('registration-component', require('./components/modal/RegistrationComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('cepmodal-component', require('./components/modal/CepModalComponent.vue').default);

Vue.component('cart-component', require('./components/CartComponent.vue').default);

Vue.component('loading', require('./../../node_modules/vue-loading-overlay/src/js/Component.vue').default);

Vue.component('mainuser-component', require('./components/account/MainUserComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('infouser-component', require('./components/account/InfoUserComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('locationuser-component', require('./components/account/LocationUserComponent.vue').default);
```

The problem with this is that every request for change pages, Laravel load my app.js for every request and I want to load only the components that belongs to the page, but I don't want to make this a SPA project.

Here an example to my page menu.blade.php + vue.js components.

```
@extends('layout/page', ['titlePage' => $titlePage, 'headerStyle' => 'menu', 'footerStyle' => 'show'])

@section('custom-css')

    <link href="{{ URL::asset('css/menu-page.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

@endsection

@section('content')

<!-- SubHeader =============================================== -->
<section class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="{{ asset('img/slides/banner_chocoffe_3.jpg') }}" data-natural-width="1400" data-natural-height="470">
    <div id="subheader">
    <div id="sub_content">
                    <div><em>Chocoffe / Le Parc</em></div>
                    <div><i class="icon_pin"></i> Recepção de pedestres - R. Le Parc, 100 - Imbiribeira, Recife - PE, 51160-280</div>
                    <div class="container-delivery-info text-center">
                        <div class="row row-delivery-info m-t-20">
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                <div class="title-delivery-info">
                                    Tempo de espera
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    0 a 50 min
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                <div class="title-delivery-info">
                                    Taxa da entrega
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    A partir de R$ 8,00
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                                <div class="title-delivery-info">
                                    Fechado <i class="icon-dot-circled icon-red"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    Abriremos as 12:00
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </div><!-- End sub_content -->
</div><!-- End subheader -->
</section><!-- End section -->
<!-- End SubHeader ============================================ -->

    <div id="position">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
                <li>Menu</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Position -->

<!-- Content ================================================== -->
<div class="container margin_60_35" id="containerPrdList">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h3 class="nomargin_top" id="starters">Destaques</h3>
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card hvr-float">
                            <div class="img-card"
                                style="background-image: url({{ asset('img/categorys/sushi.jpg') }});">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-description-promo">
                            <h4><b>Sushi</b></h4>
                            <p>Os pratos mais saborosos da culinária japonesa você encontra aqui</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card hvr-float">
                            <div class="img-card"
                                style="background-image: url('{{ asset('img/categorys/pizza.jpg') }}');">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-description-promo">
                            <h4><b>Pizza</b></h4>
                            <p>Está com aquela vontade de comer aquela pizza deliciosa? achou o lugar</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="card hvr-float">
                            <div class="img-card"
                                style="background-image: url('{{ asset('img/categorys/hamburguer.jpg') }}');">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-description-promo">
                            <h4><b>Hamburguer</b></h4>
                            <p>Gostaria de matar a fome com aquele Hamburguer delicioso? peça aqui</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>


                <prodlist-component></prodlist-component>

                </div>

                <cart-component></cart-component>

        </div><!-- End row -->
</div><!-- End container -->
<!-- End Content =============================================== -->

@endsection


@section('custom-script')

    <script src="{{ asset('core/menu-mp.js') }}"></script>

    <!-- SPECIFIC SCRIPTS -->
    <script  src="js/cat_nav_mobile.js"></script>
    <script>$('#cat_nav').mobileMenu();</script>
    <script src="js/theia-sticky-sidebar.js"></script>
    <script>
        jQuery('#sidebar').theiaStickySidebar({
        additionalMarginTop: 80
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $('#cat_nav a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var target = this.hash;
                    var $target = $(target);
                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 70
                    }, 900, 'swing', function () {
                        window.location.hash = target;
                    });
        });
    </script>

@endsection
```

My doubt is that if this is a good approach? Exist some alternative?

Comment: How about having different layout page for every category/group in your e-commerce? That way you can separate javascript files.

Comment: @user10971804 I don't understand what you trying to say, I think before to create a js file for every page and import the components but I can't import in a normal js file.

Comment: Two things, first is that with all the moving parts my feeling is the only way to know whether splitting a single long JS into multiple smaller versions will improve performance is to measure. Also measure if it is really a problem. The second is that this is what Laravel Mix is for, among other things, it allows you to set compile different Javascript files.

Comment: @Wavrik You make 2,3,4,5 or more of what you already did above then just categorized it by similarity or by group. That way you can still reuse your code to those specific category. Although the UX/UI may still look the same with other categories but at least the load will be spread. Just my theory anyway. As Josh said, you have to test it.

Comment: Thank you guys, with the comment from @JoshRumbut, I see that Laravel mix can compile how many js files I want, so I make one for each page to load the component that I want and is working. One last thing how can i transform this <prodlist-component></prodlist-component> in a real html? for a better SEO